# Javascript - Load current month htm - Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with the following code always wanting to load the page for the month of February instead of the current month. I don't see any issues but hoping someone with better javascript eyes can help.

Basically the code is pretty simple. On page load get current month then load that months .htm in to a frame. Easy peasy. Thanks in advance for any/all help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
      font-family: tahoma;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    #title {
      background-color: #333;
      border-right: 1px black dotted;
    }
    
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1200px;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      function cMonth() {
        var d = new Date();
        var q = d.getMonth();
      }

      function jan() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jan.htm")
      }

      function feb() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "feb.htm")
      }

      function mar() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "mar.htm")
      }

      function apr() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "apr.htm")
      }

      function may() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "may.htm")
      }

      function jun() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jun.htm")
      }

      function jul() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jul.htm")
      }

      function aug() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "aug.htm")
      }

      function sep() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "sep.htm")
      }

      function oct() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "oct.htm")
      }

      function nov() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "nov.htm")
      }

      function dec() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "dec.htm")
      }

      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onclick = jan;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].onclick = feb;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3].onclick = mar;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[4].onclick = apr;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[5].onclick = may;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[6].onclick = jun;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[7].onclick = jul;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[8].onclick = aug;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[9].onclick = sep;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[10].onclick = oct;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[11].onclick = nov;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[12].onclick = dec;

      if (q = 0) {
        document.getElementById('january').click() = jan;
      } else if (q = 1) {
        document.getElementById('february').click() = feb;
      } else if (q = 2) {
        document.getElementById('march').click() = mar;
      } else if (q = 3) {
        document.getElementById('april').click() = apr;
      } else if (q = 4) {
        document.getElementById('may').click() = may;
      } else if (q = 5) {
        document.getElementById('june').click() = jun;
      } else if (q = 6) {
        document.getElementById('july').click() = jul;
      } else if (q = 7) {
        document.getElementById('august').click() = aug;
      } else if (q = 8) {
        document.getElementById('september').click() = sep;
      } else if (q = 9) {
        document.getElementById('october').click() = oct;
      } else if (q = 10) {
        document.getElementById('november').click() = nov;
      } else if (q = 11) {
        document.getElementById('december').click() = dec;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="january" href="#" onclick="jan()">January</a></li>
    <li><a id="february" href="#" onclick="feb()">February</a></li>
    <li><a id="march" href="#" onclick="mar()">March</a></li>
    <li><a id="april" href="#" onclick="apr()">April</a></li>
    <li><a id="may" href="#" onclick="may()">May</a></li>
    <li><a id="june" href="#" onclick="jun()">June</a></li>
    <li><a id="july" href="#" onclick="jul()">July</a></li>
    <li><a id="august" href="#" onclick="aug()">August</a></li>
    <li><a id="september" href="#" onclick="sep()">September</a></li>
    <li><a id="october" href="#" onclick="oct()">October</a></li>
    <li><a id="november" href="#" onclick="nov()">November</a></li>
    <li><a id="december" href="#" onclick="dec()">December</a></li>
  </ul>
  <iframe sandbox="" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="sched"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The q=1 and q=2 ... are assignments not comparisons. In Javascript you do if(q==1){....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First Mistake*

Use comparison as `==` not `=`.

*Second Mistake*

`var d = new Date();var q = d.getMonth();` used inside function but never called.

*Third Mistake*

`Array index` are `zero based` so start with `0` to `11`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
      font-family: tahoma;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    #title {
      background-color: #333;
      border-right: 1px black dotted;
    }
    
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1200px;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var d = new Date();
      var q = d.getMonth();

      function jan() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jan.htm")
      }

      function feb() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "feb.htm")
      }

      function mar() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "mar.htm")
      }

      function apr() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "apr.htm")
      }

      function may() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "may.htm")
      }

      function jun() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jun.htm")
      }

      function jul() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jul.htm")
      }

      function aug() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "aug.htm")
      }

      function sep() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "sep.htm")
      }

      function oct() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "oct.htm")
      }

      function nov() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "nov.htm")
      }

      function dec() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "dec.htm")
      }

      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = jan;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onclick = feb;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].onclick = mar;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[3].onclick = apr;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[4].onclick = may;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[5].onclick = jun;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[6].onclick = jul;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[7].onclick = aug;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[8].onclick = sep;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[9].onclick = oct;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[10].onclick = nov;
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[11].onclick = dec;
      debugger;
      if (q == 0) {
        document.getElementById('january').click() = jan;
      } else if (q == 1) {
        document.getElementById('february').click() = feb;
      } else if (q == 2) {
        document.getElementById('march').click() = mar;
      } else if (q == 3) {
        document.getElementById('april').click() = apr;
      } else if (q == 4) {
        document.getElementById('may').click() = may;
      } else if (q == 5) {
        document.getElementById('june').click() = jun;
      } else if (q == 6) {
        document.getElementById('july').click() = jul;
      } else if (q == 7) {
        document.getElementById('august').click() = aug;
      } else if (q == 8) {
        document.getElementById('september').click() = sep;
      } else if (q == 9) {
        document.getElementById('october').click() = oct;
      } else if (q == 10) {
        document.getElementById('november').click() = nov;
      } else if (q == 11) {
        document.getElementById('december').click() = dec;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="january" href="#" onclick="jan()">January</a></li>
    <li><a id="february" href="#" onclick="feb()">February</a></li>
    <li><a id="march" href="#" onclick="mar()">March</a></li>
    <li><a id="april" href="#" onclick="apr()">April</a></li>
    <li><a id="may" href="#" onclick="may()">May</a></li>
    <li><a id="june" href="#" onclick="jun()">June</a></li>
    <li><a id="july" href="#" onclick="jul()">July</a></li>
    <li><a id="august" href="#" onclick="aug()">August</a></li>
    <li><a id="september" href="#" onclick="sep()">September</a></li>
    <li><a id="october" href="#" onclick="oct()">October</a></li>
    <li><a id="november" href="#" onclick="nov()">November</a></li>
    <li><a id="december" href="#" onclick="dec()">December</a></li>
  </ul>
  <iframe sandbox="" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="sched"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually comparsion should be done with the === operator

Comment: You are the MAN! Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonH. If this helps you, please mark as a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below works as expected. It will display the page of the current month.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
      font-family: tahoma;
    }

    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }

    #title {
      background-color: #333;
      border-right: 1px black dotted;
    }

    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1200px;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {      
        var d = new Date();
        var q = d.getMonth();

        if (q == 0) {
            document.getElementById('january').click();
        } else if (q == 1) {
            document.getElementById('february').click();
        } else if (q == 2) {
            document.getElementById('march').click();
        } else if (q == 3) {
            document.getElementById('april').click();
        } else if (q == 4) {
            document.getElementById('may').click();
        } else if (q == 5) {
            document.getElementById('june').click();
        } else if (q == 6) {
            document.getElementById('july').click();
        } else if (q == 7) {
            document.getElementById('august').click();
        } else if (q == 8) {
            document.getElementById('september').click();
        } else if (q == 9) {
            document.getElementById('october').click();
        } else if (q == 10) {
            document.getElementById('november').click();
        } else if (q == 11) {
            document.getElementById('december').click();
        }
    };  

    function jan() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jan.htm")
    }

    function feb() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "feb.htm")
    }

    function mar() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "mar.htm")
    }

    function apr() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "apr.htm")
    }

    function may() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "may.htm")
    }

    function jun() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jun.htm")
    }

    function jul() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jul.htm")
    }

    function aug() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "aug.htm")
    }

    function sep() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "sep.htm")
    }

    function oct() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "oct.htm")
    }

    function nov() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "nov.htm")
    }

    function dec() {
        document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "dec.htm")
    }          
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="january" href="#" onclick="jan()">January</a></li>
    <li><a id="february" href="#" onclick="feb()">February</a></li>
    <li><a id="march" href="#" onclick="mar()">March</a></li>
    <li><a id="april" href="#" onclick="apr()">April</a></li>
    <li><a id="may" href="#" onclick="may()">May</a></li>
    <li><a id="june" href="#" onclick="jun()">June</a></li>
    <li><a id="july" href="#" onclick="jul()">July</a></li>
    <li><a id="august" href="#" onclick="aug()">August</a></li>
    <li><a id="september" href="#" onclick="sep()">September</a></li>
    <li><a id="october" href="#" onclick="oct()">October</a></li>
    <li><a id="november" href="#" onclick="nov()">November</a></li>
    <li><a id="december" href="#" onclick="dec()">December</a></li>
  </ul>
  <iframe sandbox="" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="sched"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code changes**

1. Removed the following codes because they are overkill. The onclick attribute on each anchor tags are sufficient.
2. Used == instead of = on the if conditions.
3. Removed the "= jan" from the following and do the same with the rest of the same codes.

   document.getElementById('january').click() = jan;
4. Revised the code inside the window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to all for the fast responses. You guys are always great!

Looks like I had a few things wrong with my original code. Below is the correct snippet thanks to Nawed Khan, Yogen Darji, kevinSpacey and visualjoel!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
      font-family: tahoma;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    #title {
      background-color: #333;
      border-right: 1px black dotted;
    }
    
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1200px;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var d = new Date();
      var q = d.getMonth();

      if (q == 0) {
        document.getElementById('january').click();
      } else if (q == 1) {
        document.getElementById('february').click();
      } else if (q == 2) {
        document.getElementById('march').click();
      } else if (q == 3) {
        document.getElementById('april').click();
      } else if (q == 4) {
        document.getElementById('may').click();
      } else if (q == 5) {
        document.getElementById('june').click();
      } else if (q == 6) {
        document.getElementById('july').click();
      } else if (q == 7) {
        document.getElementById('august').click();
      } else if (q == 8) {
        document.getElementById('september').click();
      } else if (q == 9) {
        document.getElementById('october').click();
      } else if (q == 10) {
        document.getElementById('november').click();
      } else if (q == 11) {
        document.getElementById('december').click();
      }
    };

    function jan() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jan.htm")
    }

    function feb() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "feb.htm")
    }

    function mar() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "mar.htm")
    }

    function apr() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "apr.htm")
    }

    function may() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "may.htm")
    }

    function jun() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jun.htm")
    }

    function jul() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "jul.htm")
    }

    function aug() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "aug.htm")
    }

    function sep() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "sep.htm")
    }

    function oct() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "oct.htm")
    }

    function nov() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "nov.htm")
    }

    function dec() {
      document.querySelector(".sched").setAttribute("src", "dec.htm")
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="january" href="#" onclick="jan()">January</a></li>
    <li><a id="february" href="#" onclick="feb()">February</a></li>
    <li><a id="march" href="#" onclick="mar()">March</a></li>
    <li><a id="april" href="#" onclick="apr()">April</a></li>
    <li><a id="may" href="#" onclick="may()">May</a></li>
    <li><a id="june" href="#" onclick="jun()">June</a></li>
    <li><a id="july" href="#" onclick="jul()">July</a></li>
    <li><a id="august" href="#" onclick="aug()">August</a></li>
    <li><a id="september" href="#" onclick="sep()">September</a></li>
    <li><a id="october" href="#" onclick="oct()">October</a></li>
    <li><a id="november" href="#" onclick="nov()">November</a></li>
    <li><a id="december" href="#" onclick="dec()">December</a></li>
  </ul>
  <iframe sandbox="" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="sched"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```